# Build sql query with string builder and a lot of parameters

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am building my query using loops

```
for (var i = 0; i <  query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append($@"(
                                MatchType = {(int)query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].MatchType}
                        AND     EntityType = {(int)query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].EntityType}
                        AND     MatchFieldType = {(int)query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].MatchFieldType}
                        AND     (
                                    (
                                        MatchValue = '{query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].MatchValue1}'
                                        OR MatchValue = {query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].MatchValue2Or ?? "Null"}
                                    )
                                AND
                                    (
                                        {query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].MatchValue2And ?? "Null"} is Null
                                        OR MatchValue2 is Null
                                        OR MatchValue2 = {query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].MatchValue2And ?? "Null"}
                                    )
                                 )
                          )");

            if (i != query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy.Count - 1)
                sb.Append($@"
                            OR");
        }
```

But I have the problem with this

```
{query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].MatchValue2And ?? "Null"} is Null
```

If it Null It'll work, otherwise the real value will be without ""

The thing is I cant use something like

```
@MatchValue
```

Because I have the list of parameters with the same name which differs only by it's number in the List the names will be the same and It won't map it properly

Comment: Post Full Code of the function.

Comment: you are injecting literals into SQL; that is a very very very bad idea... you say "The thing is I cant use something like `@MatchValue` Because I have the list of parameters with the same name which differs only by it's number in the List the names will be the same and It won't map it properly` - I don't see how that is a problem: just create whatever additional args you need to fill out the query. Can you perhaps explain more what it is that is stopping you using regular parameters here? because I don't get it...

Comment: I have the list of objects BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy. I don't know how many. And every object has smth like MatchType, EntityType  etc. But the value of its fields differs in every loop for every object. How would I map the parameters using @ and depending on the current step of loop. The names a the same and the values are not. And all of that has to be combined in one query

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i <  query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy.Count; i++)
{
    var match = query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i];
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@matchType{i}", (int)match.MatchType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@entityType{i}", (int)match.EntityType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@fieldType{i}", (int)match.MatchFieldType);

    sb.Append($@"(
                            MatchType = @matchType{i}
                    AND     EntityType = @entityType{i}
                    AND     MatchFieldType = @fieldType{i}
    ... etc
```

Add additional parameters per required element - so there will be `@matchType0`, `@matchType1`, etc - then you have no injection vulnerabilities. One thing to watch: parameters with a **value** of `null` *are not sent*, so check for `null` and either generate different SQL, or be sure to set the parameter value to `DBNull.Value` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is terrible way of structuring SQL. This SQL has many issues. First and most important thing is it is open to SQL Injection Attacks. But, It has also other performance related issues where SQL Query is changing whenever different value is provided.

I Suggest you to use parameterized SQL. here is the most basic example for it.
Please note that code may be subject to change according to the library that you are going to use.

```
// 1. declare command object with parameter @City
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "select * from Customers where city = @City", conn);

// 2. define parameters used in command object
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@City";
param.Value         = inputCity;
```

if we turn back to your case. The Final Code would be like this:

```
"... SQL ...
MatchType = @matchType AND
 ... SQL ..."
```

The code needs to be like

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matchType", (int)match.MatchType);
```

and for the null values you may consider to use

```
DbNull.Value
```